# Capturing ssl keys for kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, wireshark

I want to decrypt kubectl requests to kubernetes api server (over tls) with wireshark (for `exec -it` subcommand). I found that there's `SSLKEYLOGFILE` variable that can be used by wireshark for decrypting tls packets but kubectl doesn't log tls session keys into that file. Is there any option for kubectl to log sslkeys into that file? or is there any other option for capturing and viewing exec raw network packets?

Thanks

Comment: I found this blog post about it:
https://ahmet.im/blog/kubectl-man-in-the-middle/

Answer (score 2):

- If you requirement is just to capture the requests betten apiserver & kubectl command. add `--v=11` it will show all the requests that are happening between kubectl & apiserver.

Ex:

```
kubectl get nodes --v=11
```

Comment: This doesn't works for kubectl exec -it